# App vs Mobile Website this one bugs ME

Tags: android, iphone, jquery-mobile, mobile, mobile-safari

Okay, I'm going to rant for a moment because I don't get why people are confusing the differences. Or maybe I'm just not getting it.

Why do people call a Mobile Website an App when its not an App its a website to be exact a Mobile Website. App is something you have to download from the Apple/Droid Store and install it. I get it Apple, Droid and JQuery Mobile want to give the impression that its an App but its not even remotely close to an App. There's no Object C in any of it... It's HTML with some pics. So could someone please clear this up for me am I wrong for saying this?

Its very frustrating because clients think when we say app they thing something you download from the Apple store and install.

Thanks I have to get this off my chest!

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A mobile website is not an app, you are correct.  It is just a different flavor of HTML markup to be loaded on a mobile device to provide a better viewing experience.

It could be loaded from within an app, if the website is embedded within one for additional purposes, such as taking advantage of other software in order to share information with people or provide additional capabilities alongside the app.  But, in and of itself, a mobile website is just a website.

Answer (score 0):

No way a mobile website is an app. It's not.

There is a term in programming called 'Native'. 
Native means, you develop the app/website with the language that the processor of the device can handle, and give it's maximum capacity to use its full power.

A website turned mobile friendly, is just a website that runs on an external server, which has had extra work on it, to look nicely on mobiles.

Assume there is no internet, does the website-turned-to-app work ? No. it does not.

Your clients need to use some logic and read.

Comment: I agree but I see a lot of people use the word app for a mobile site and that just fires me up! It's not an APP its a Website. Smartphones have Browser like a desktop and we view websites on them not apps :)

Comment: well, you can't blame them totally, as there are apps that work on web browsers (chrome apps) , or even inside websites that run inside browsers (facebook apps)... it is just intermingles, and an app can not have several meanings, depending on the angle it is being seen from.. for the hard core java/android developer, an app is and will be the one written in java and uploaded on google play :) (or kindle's store)